# Issue with Fetching Data from Alphavantage API in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, fetch-api, alpha-vantage

Im encountering an issue with  fetching data from the Alphavantage API using Google Apps Script. I have a script set up to fetch data for four specific functions ("OVERVIEW", "BALANCE_SHEET", "CASH_FLOW", "INCOME_STATEMENT"), with the ticker symbol dynamically retrieved from cell I6 in my Google Sheets.

However, when I run the script, it fetches data successfully for the ticker symbol, for the first 4 cycles it fetches data succesfuly (as it should) but in fifth, additional unwanted cycle the function name passed to the API changes to undefined, resulting in a URL like: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=undefined&symbol=aapl&apikey=9R6A1KGBO4C1CYWD.

I've checked my code thoroughly and ensured that the function names are correctly passed to the getStock function, yet the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

```
const apiKey = "XXXXXX"; 
const alphaVantageBaseUrl = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query";

async function fetchData(functionUrl) {
  try {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheetWithTicker = spreadsheet.getSheets()[2]; 
    const tickerSymbol = sheetWithTicker.getRange("I6").getValue();
    const url = `${functionUrl}&symbol=${tickerSymbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`;
    console.log("URL to fetch: " + url);

    const response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unable to fetch data. Err: ${response.getResponseCode()}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error occurred during fetch: ${error}`);
  }
}

async function fetchAllData() {
  try {
    const functionUrls = [
      `${alphaVantageBaseUrl}?function=OVERVIEW`,
      `${alphaVantageBaseUrl}?function=BALANCE_SHEET`,
      `${alphaVantageBaseUrl}?function=INCOME_STATEMENT`,
      `${alphaVantageBaseUrl}?function=CASH_FLOW`
    ];

    const fetchedData = await Promise.all(functionUrls.map(url => fetchData(url)));
    console.log("Fetched data:", fetchedData);
      
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error occurred: ${error}`);
  }
}

fetchAllData();
```

console logs:

```
URL to fetch: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX
URL to fetch: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX
URL to fetch: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX
URL to fetch: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CASH_FLOW&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX
URL to fetch: undefined&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX   
Error   Error: Error occurred during fetch: Exception: Bad request: http://undefined&symbol=aapl&apikey=XXXXXX
fetchData   @ Code.gs:19
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that will cause that extra fetch. You're not substituting a variable after `function=`, so there's no way for anything other than the four `functionUrls` you define to be used.

Comment: Is your showing script the same as the script in which your issue occurred? I guess that this might be the same as Barmar's comment. And, if you are actually using your showing script, when a function `fetchAllData` is run, the function is run 2 times. Please be careful about this. As additional information, in the current stage, Google Apps Script runs with the synchronous process. So, in your situation, await/async is not required to be used.